# How to remove unwanted spaces from a cell using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the below mentioned data.

```
,name,link,address
0,Aasia Steel Industrial Group,http://www.aasiasteel.com/,"
Address

                                        1 
                                                Saudi Arabia 
                                    "
1,ADES,http://investors.adihgroup.com/,"
Address

                                        Al-Kifah Tower 
                                                King Fahad Road 
                                                    Dhahran 
                                                Saudi Arabia 
                                    "
2,AEC,https://www.aecl.com,"
Address

                                        King Khalid International Airport. 
                                                Industrial Estate P.O.Box 90916, 
                                                    Riyadh 11623, 
                                                    Saudi Arabia 
                                    "
```

There is a lot of unwanted spaces. I tries using the below functions but I am not able to clean my cells.

```
df['address']=df.address.str.strip()
```

In the console the  the output is address column follows:

```
\nAddress\r\n\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tAl-Kifah
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df['address'].apply(lambda x:' '.join(x.split()))
```

If the column has other variable excpet string then we can use:

```
df['address'].apply(lambda x:' '.join(x.split()) if hasattr(x,'lower') else x)
```

Comment: when I am using this I am getting this error 
File "main.py", line 33, in <module>
    df['address'].str.apply(lambda x:' '.join(x.split()))
AttributeError: 'StringMethods' object has no attribute 'apply'

Comment: Sorry I mistakenly add str method in apply. Now you can use

Comment: can u help me with another problem if its ok? @Mazhar

Comment: Sure, whats the problem..?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70921814/getting-a-not-subscriptable-when-running-a-web-scraping-script I posted this question. can you please have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

As your address cells have newline, it's better to split it with newline character.
Following solution will also remove trailing and ending spaces using **strip()** method.

```
def format_address(address):
    slines = address.splitlines() #split cell into lines
    slines = [ l.strip() for l in lines ] # to remove trailing/ending spaces
    slines.remove("") #to remove empty strings
    return ",".join(slines) # joining all lines with comma
df.address = df.address.apply(format_address)
```